# PIE.htc problem in archive.php, category.php, tag.php wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags, archive, categories, css3pie

I'm using PIE.htc to handle CSS3 in IE.
I put PIE.htc in the root, and I use behavior: url(PIE.htc) in the css.

for excample:

```
#content{
....
.....
behaviour: url(PIE.htc)

}
```

It works just fine in all pages, except the PIE.htc somehow won't load in category.php, archive.php and tag.php.

Then I decided to change the path of my PIE.htc by overwrite the css of each archive.php, category.php, tag.php become like this:

```
#content{
behaviour: url(../PIE.htc)
}
```

It worked ok in the first page of my archive.php, category.php, tag.php, but when I go to the next pages of my archive.php, category.php, tag.php, PIE.htc won't load anymore.

I've tried to change the path with behaviour: url(../../PIE.htc) but didn't work.

How to solve this path issue of PIE.htc for archive.php, category.php, tag.php in wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a URI relative to the root of the site. That means it should start with a slash. For example, if the file is in a directory named CSS which is at the same level as index.php:

```
url(/CSS/PIE.htc)
```

This refers to the same URL no matter what the URL of the current page is.

Comment: so I should create folder css in the root of inside the theme folder?

Comment: You do not have to create any folder anywhere. You can put the file anywhere you want. Just refer to it by the path from the root of the site. If it's in your theme folder, then use `url(/wp-content/themes/themename/PIE.htc)`.

Comment: Hi Dan,

I've tried to change the path to url(/wp-content/themes/themename/PIE.htc) but since I do this in my localhost, I change the path to url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/themename/PIE.htc).

It works now. Thanks.

Is there a way to let the url(/wp-content/themes/themename/PIE.htc) path working in localhost?

Comment: Yes, run your local web server the same as your web host does, with real virtual hosts. It makes development 100% easier when your URLs are the same locally as on the production server.